# Set Home button to reject calls

Tags: calls, home-button

I had an android where i could reject calls with the home button. Default behavior in lock mode with unanswered call.
With my new phone that doesnt work anymore.
I can see the option to set Answering calls with the home button. 
But  I want the opposite action.
When the phone is in the pocket and i need to immediately reject a call when i forget to put the device in do not disturb mode, the only button that solves that issue is the home button.

Is it possible to have the home button set to reject calls ?

SAMSUNG S7   (NOT rooted)

**EDIT: I tried using tasker, but there is no Home button event condition.**

Comment: This could be possible using an [automation](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) app like [tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) (not tested, so just a comment with this hint): Condition = incoming call + home-button tapped, action = hangup.

Comment: sounds like a good idea,  except i cant find the Tasker hardware event HOME button

Comment: Ouch, yes: that's probably not there as it's no "hardware" button but a soft-button – didn't think of that. But is "swiping left" to reject the call so much more difficult?

Comment: I was hoping to do so in the dark so to speak, without removing phone from pocket.

Comment: Ah. If it weren't for "in the pocket", an alternative would be an app like [Air Call-Accept](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.necta.aircall_accept.free) where you simply accept/reject calls with a hand motion over the proximity sensor. I don't know about other options currently, sorry.